# Editing just the home page (at index = 0)?

Tags: flutter

I have simple code for an application with bottom and side navigation. I am attempting to edit JUST the home page (at index = 0), but am unsure of where I should place the code for adding to this page and was hoping for any advice.

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('OBTAIN'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit `_widgetOptions` on first Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the first Widget in the `_widgetOptions` like this

```dart
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('This is the new home page'),
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
```